# Linux libraries manuals

Tags: c, linux

Where can I find the official manuals of the Linux libraries for C? For instance the manual of the pthread library? I found only [this big file](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/pdf/libc.pdf).

Comment: I usually type `man <the_thing>` in google. Man pages [are part of linux man-pages project](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). The official standard is [posix](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/). But asking for library recommendations is offtopic for stackoverflow - this is a forum for programming problems and how to solve them

Comment: You can also view the documentation for glibc in [html form](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_mono/libc.html), which I find way nicer, because links work and you can jump from one location to another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on the terminal type:

```
man function_name
```

For example:

```
man pthread_create
```

For showing all functions of pthread library:

```
man pthreads
```

For seeing the options of man command line type:

```
man man
```

Comment: can i download a pdf of the library pthread?

Comment: `pdf of the library pthread` man pages are in the form of... man pages written specifically for `man` utility. Still, just copy the text to your favourite editor of choice and generate pdf from it. [Posix standard](https://www.google.com/search?q=posix+pdf) is easily available in the form of a pdf.

Comment: man -k  to search.  All the man pages are on the WWW too

Answer (score 0):

Pthread is a [POSIX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX) standard.

You could read [this pthread tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/pthreads/) or [pthreads(7)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/pthreads.7.html). Use the [man(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/man.1.html) command in a terminal.

There are good paper books about Pthreads. I enjoyed reading and recommend 
Butenhof *Programming POSIX threads* book  ISBN-13: 978-0201633924